# Grid inside of TabPanel throws Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have followed all the steps and copied all the files from [nextjs-with-typescript](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript), every thing looks fine but adding `Grid` inside `TabPanel` in following example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Button, Container, CssBaseline, Grid, IconButton, Paper, styled, Tooltip, useMediaQuery, useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import PortfolioItem from './PortfolioItem';



interface TabPanelProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    index: number;
    value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
        >
            {value === index && (
                <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
                    <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
    return {
        id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
        'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
}

const UserPortfolio = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <CssBaseline />
            
            <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
                    <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
                        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
                    </Tabs>
                </Box>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item lg={4} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                            <PortfolioItem />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item lg={4} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                            <PortfolioItem />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item lg={4} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}>
                            <PortfolioItem />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabPanel>                    
            </Box>
        </>

    );
}

export default UserPortfolio
```

`<Grid container spacing={2}>` when placed `TabPanel` gives error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Call Stack
throwOnHydrationMismatch
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (12507:0)
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (12520:0)
updateHostComponent
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19902:0)
beginWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (21618:0)
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4164:0)
Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4213:0)
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4277:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (27451:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25738:0)
workLoop
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

and console log:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <p>.
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Grid (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/material/Grid/Grid.js:390:87)
    at p
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Typography (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/material/Typography/Typography.js:98:87)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:34:72)
    at div
    at TabPanel (webpack-internal:///./src/components/UserPortfolio.tsx:72:13)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:34:72)
    at UserPortfolio (webpack-internal:///./src/components/UserPortfolio.tsx:110:66)
    at main
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:34:72)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-6a883da9.browser.esm.js:57:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:34:72)
    at main
    at Home
    at InnerThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:21:70)
    at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/private-theming/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:43:5)
    at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:40:5)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:30:13)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:62:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:301:63)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:850:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:61:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:171:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:346:11)
```

any help in this case is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error as you are passing your Grid as a Typography child.
In your TabPanel part

```
function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

return (
    <div
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
    >
        {value === index && (
            <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
                ***{children}***
            </Box>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

}